# Raphael JS - paper.remove

Tags: javascript, raphael

Just getting started with Raphael.

Now I'm finding that `paper.remove()` is generating a script error:

```
 "SCRIPT5009: 'removed' is undefined
```

Is this a script bug?

My variable `paper` is initialized thus:

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);
```

My HTML body has:

```
<div id="canvas_container"></div>
```

---

This is more info --
I am using Raphael 2.0 which I just downloaded again.  Running IE9.  Following is the Raphael JS function that is highlighted as the problem:

```
R.prototype.remove = function () {

        eve("remove", this);
        this.canvas.parentNode && this.canvas.parentNode.removeChild(this.canvas);
        for (var i in this) {
            this[i] = removed(i);
        }
    };
```

the line ... removed(i) is highlighted --> SCRIPT5009: 'removed' is undefined

BTW I am new to this forum.  Is there a way to respond to a thread other than "Answer Your Question"?

Comment: Apart from answering a question, you can only enter-in comments.

Answer (score 4):

I've run across this a couple of times. The line 4443 method as suggested by sudoko-san does work in browsers but not backwards compatible with IE-7 & 8 (the whole point of using raphael).

Another work around is to implement the following code in your javascript:

```
try{
    paper.remove();
}
catch (error) {
    // this catches the error and allows you to proceed along nicely
}
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've supplied enough information to answer this question.

- What version of Raphael are you using?
- On what browser?
- Is it being loaded up correctly - can you create any Raphael objects?

If all you're doing is deleting the paper, see the fiddle below.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/yVzXF/)

It seems to work fine for me with Raphael 1.5.2

Hope that helps (even slightly).

Comment: I just tried your JSFiddle and get the same error.  Maybe a problem in version 2.0 of Raphael?

Comment: I found a Raphael version 0.8.2 and tried paper.remove() and IT WORKS. So must be a bug in latest released version.

Comment: I see this was opened as a problem about 3 hours ago on github.  Suggested work around is to change this[i]=removed[i]; to this[i]=null; -- line 4443 in Raphael 2.0 library.  This seems to work-- at least paper.remove() now works.